# OpenCart проблемы с базой данных Could not load database driver mmysqli

Tags: база-данных, opencart

Перенес сайт на новый хостинг, но выдаёт такую ошибку `Could not load database driver mmysqli` при редактирований config.php файлов проблема не решается

Comment: Конфиг скиньте (пути можно потереть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.php и admin/config.php

```
// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
```

и если никак, то go-go-go смотреть, какая субд на сервере.

Comment: ну вот и я так думаю, что ошибка тут

Comment: скорей всего, но я не уточнял что версия Opencart 2.x попробую вправить

Answer (score 2):

если вопрос еще актуален-проверьте, установлен ли на хостинге драйвер MySQL ND и проверьте наличие записи вида

```
    --with-mysqli
```

Comment: Спасибо но уже решили.